# CakePHP 3.x case statement on order

Tags: cakephp, sql-order-by, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to use a CASE statement on the order of a MySQL statement in CakePHP 3.x app. The simple select is as follows:

```
$articles = $this->Articles->find()
    ->where($conditions)   
    ->order(function ($exp, $q) {
        return $exp->addCase(
            [
                $q->newExpr()->gt('Articles.modified', (new Time())->subDays(365)) // article has been updated in the last x days
                    ],
            ['priority'], # values matching conditions
            ['string'] # type of each value
        );
    })
->limit(15)
->all();
```

The following SQL is generated:

```
SELECT `Articles`.`id` AS `Articles__id`, .... 
FROM `articles` `Articles` 
WHERE (`publish` < :c0 AND `Articles`.`publish` > :c1) 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN `Articles`.`modified` > :c2 THEN :param3 END LIMIT 15
```

The case statement is not correct because it is missing the DESC order which should come after the 'END' - see this fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8df161/5

I'm not sure if this is a limitation with how CakePHP handles CASE?

Further I require a second order after the case statement to order by 'publish' desc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressions passed to `Query::order()` must generate everything required by the `ORDER BY` clause, including the direction keyword.

If the expression that you're using doesn't support that, then you can use [**`Query::oderAsc()`**](https://api.cakephp.org/3.8/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_orderAsc) or [**`Query::oderDesc()`**](https://api.cakephp.org/3.8/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_orderDesc), which will append the respective direction keyword accordingly.

```php
$query = $this->Articles->find();
$query
    ->where($conditions)
    ->orderDesc(
        $query->newExpr()->addCase(/* ... */)
    )
    // ...
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Selecting Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-data)**

Comment: I had already read about orderDesc in the book - when II change my order -> orderDesc: 'sql' => 'SQL could not be generated for this query as it is incomplete.',

Comment: @AlanA That message there is debugging info, and it doesn't show the actual underlying exception, you should run the query to receive the actual error.

Comment: if I let the sql execute the ORDER is not applied, the tail-end of the query is:  WHERE (`publish` < :c0 AND `Articles`.`publish` > :c1) ORDER BY  DESC LIMIT 15' - the case is completely ignored with orderDesc. I also have a warning: Warning (4096): Object of class Closure could not be converted to string

Comment: @AlanA Looks like closures are not supported in `oderAsc()`/`orderDesc()`, I thought support for that has been added quite some time ago, I must have mixed that up with something else. You'll have to pass the expression directly, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I guess this will be fixed in a future release? I have this working now with the direct expression, appreciate your help.

Comment: @AlanA I've pushed PRs for [**`4.x`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/14646) and [**`3.x`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/14649), it should be available as of `4.1` and probably `3.9`.